# Assigning servername to a local ip in apache/ubuntu

Tags: apache2

I have a apache server running on ubuntu 10.04. i wanted to give the server a name. so i added a name called sdk in /etc/apache/sites-available/sdk with the following

```
VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName sdk.sat
    ServerAlias *.sdk.sat
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory /var/www>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
```

Now, I can access this web address thorught the lan using its ip address 192.168.1.5. But i want it to be accessed by the server name sdk.sat. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how wide you want this domain to work. If this is only for your personal use, you can add the following line to your /etc/hosts, and it would start working on your computer. Unless you are willing to buy sdk.sat from a domain registrar, you would also need to add the same entry to any other clients willing to access the site.

```
127.0.0.1 sdk.sat
```

Note that you'd need admin rights to edit the hosts file. So use `gksudo gedit /etc/hosts`

For any other computer make sure to use a network accessible ip address, such as 192.168.x.y(if its a LAN) or perhaps your internet accessible IP address.